# How to separate each result with a comma in PHP

Tags: php, variables

So I'm using:

```
<?php print $variable; ?>
```

and sometimes there are multiple variables being printed, but I'm not able to tell how many. Is there a way of printing the variables separated by a comma, but only when there are more than one?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `implode` function.

Answer (score 1):

This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

```
<?php
  var_dump($variable);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your $variable is an array count it like count($variable) and than put you condition like 
if(count($variable)>1) { $imp=implode(',',$variable); }

hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

If it's not an array

```
<?php /* somwhere before... */ $sep = ''; ?>
<?php print $sep.$variable; $sep = ',' ?>
```

If it's array

```
<?php print implode( ',', $variable ); ?>
```